# Match string in shortcode using regex

Tags: php, regex

I have this shortcode in my page content in Wordpress. I need to get the value of **"layout"** and the value from **"slug"**

So I need the values: **listing & aircraft** extracted from the string

I am looking for the lowest possible hit to performance. I am trying to get these values from the save_post hook so I don't have access to the normal shortcode $atts parameter.

```
'[vc_row][vc_column width="2/3"]

[cpt_categories layout="listing" view="grid" items_per_row="4" orderby="title" order="ASC" slug="aircraft"]

[/vc_column][vc_column width="1/3"][/vc_column][/vc_row]'
```

When using the native WP function [shortcode_parse_atts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/shortcode_atts) I get close but there are some issues:

```
$atts = shortcode_parse_atts($post->post_content);
var_dump($atts);
array 
  0 =>  '[vc_row][vc_column' 
  1 =>  'width="2/3"][cpt_categories' 
  'layout' =>  'listing' 
  'view'   =>  'grid' 
  'items_per_row' =>  '4' 
  'orderby' =>  'title' 
  'order' =>  'ASC' 
  2 =>  'slug="aircraft"][/vc_column][vc_column' 
  3 =>  'width="1/3"][/vc_column][/vc_row]'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those two values are literally all you need, then Regex could be a reasonable solution here.  *(just be careful about the whole "hammer and nails" thing with Regex and HTML)*

Match group 1 in `layout="([^"]*)"` will get you the **listing** value.

Match group 1 in `slug="([^"]*)"` will get you the **aircraft** value.

They both work on your example string (as tested at https://regex101.com/).